# Extract coordinates from polyline google maps to save in SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-maps

With this code I can have the coordinates, but how can I recover it in the C# side to manipulate it, let say to insert inside a database?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function(line) {
  alert(line.getPath().getArray().toString());
});
```